# WSO2: Caching Keys and Response

Tags: caching, wso2

I am a beginner in middleware technology. I have started with WSO2. Now I learned that WSO2 has a caching feature at different places. Two of them is at Key Manager caches Keys and Response Caching.

My question is very simple (naive), that if we are caching wrong Response, we will get the response again.
For example: 
I hit this dummy API request `http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees` which supposed to give a list of employees, but it gives me null or something else. Now, this response is cached in response cache, which means I will keep on getting null. Which is wrong. Caching makes sense, but it is caching all responses, wrong and right. So how it handled, what's the concept?

Similarily for Key Manager. What is the point of caching keys at both the API Gateway level and Key Manager level? We anyways have to re-generate it if it is a wrong key or expired key.

Please answer. My questions sound naive but appreciate if you can explain.

Comment: Which product are you asking this about. The API Manager, or maybe the Enterprise integrator?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agree with you. Ideally, the cacheable responses should be picked based on the status code. I just created a [feature improvement request](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/5683).

However, this is already supported by the runtime, only the UI is missing it.

So you can make this working by changing a configuration file.

For that, open `repository/resources/api_templates/velocity_template.xml` and search for `<cache scope="per-host" collector="false"`. (Note `collector=false`)

Then, add the `<protocol>` tag just above the `<implementation>` tag like this.

```
<cache scope="per-host" collector="false" hashGenerator="org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.REQUESTHASHGenerator" timeout="$!responseCacheTimeOut">
    <protocol type="HTTP">
       <methods>*</methods>
       <headersToExcludeInHash/>
       <responseCodes>2[0-9][0-0]</responseCodes>
       <enableCacheControl>false</enableCacheControl>
       <includeAgeHeader>false</includeAgeHeader>
       <hashGenerator>org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.digest.REQUESTHASHGenerator</hashGenerator>
    </protocol>
    <implementation type="memory" maxSize="500"/>
</cache>
```

Note the regex for 2xx responses in `responseCodes`. I hope this answers your 1st question.

---

Regarding the key caches, yes, there are caches at both gateway and keymanager. But by default, only the gateway cache is enabled.

```
<CacheConfigurations>
    <!-- Enable/Disable token caching at the Gateway-->
    <EnableGatewayTokenCache>true</EnableGatewayTokenCache>
    <!-- Enable/Disable API resource caching at the Gateway-->
    <EnableGatewayResourceCache>true</EnableGatewayResourceCache>
    <!-- Enable/Disable API key validation information caching at key-management server -->
    <EnableKeyManagerTokenCache>false</EnableKeyManagerTokenCache>
```

And there are cases where some want to disable gateway cache and enable keymanager cache, for example when the gateway is in DMZ.